# How to use a code igniter class in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

The class I wish to use is: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl/blob/master/libraries/Curl.php

How can I use this in a Wordpress project? Do I just take out the code igniter specific snippets out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you need remove `log_message()` function calls and codeIgniter `get_instance()` call

Summary.. remove lines 233-238

```
    // If no a protocol in URL, assume its a CI link
    if ( ! preg_match('!^\w+://! i', $url))
    {
        $this->_ci->load->helper('url');
        $url = site_url($url);
    }
```

line 31-32

```
$this->_ci =& get_instance();
log_message('debug', 'cURL Class Initialized');
```

and line 36

```
log_message('error', 'cURL Class - PHP was not built with cURL enabled. Rebuild PHP with --with-curl to use cURL.') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the class uses codeigniter's url helper.  So, you would have to take a look at this:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

And re-factor the class in the places where those functions are used.  For instance, line 237 of your class uses the codeigniter site_url function.